# Smart watch with eSim and continues heart rate and blood pressure

Tags: smart-watches

I'm looking for a smart watch model with eSim that gives me continues heart rate and blood pressure monitoring 24/7 with data transmitted to the cloud so I can see the reading from my PC.

Any suggestions for watches/applications for these watches?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here